# How to find last 8 digit of number 0000548795846

Tags: php, regex, numbers

I want to find last 8 digit of number 0000548795846 in php.

Its done fine when I use string but I have some problem with Integer starts with zero.

Comment: You have no code to critique, but as an integer consider using modulus 10

Answer (score 1):

Try with -

```
substr(" 0000548795846", -1, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example what is happening is that, PHP by default considers the number starting with 0 (zero) as octal number i.e base 8, and you are expecting it as decimal.

When PHP comes across any number starting with zero it converts it into decimal equivalent of the actual number for ex. 0000548795846 gets converted into 44 decimal, so there is no length >= 8 present.

So, Solution is to convert the number in string format. Then use substr() with appropriate arguments, as suggsted by "sgt"